# How can I handle the info I get from file while reading in c++?

Tags: c++, file, stream, fstream

```
int i = 5;
char c = 'n';
string st = "cool";
ofstream my("we.txt");
my <<st<<","<<c<<","<<i<<","<<endl;
string s;

ifstream your("we.txt");
while(your){

    getline(your, st, ',');
    your>>c;
    your.ignore(1);
    your>>i;
    your.ignore(1);
    cout<<st<<","<<c<<","<<i<<endl;
}
my.close();
```

I don't even know what your.ignore(1) stands for, but somehow it works. The problem is that it print the result twice, why?
Can someone explain me how to handle the info that I've written in the file? If I wanted to save in a file 3 info string trade, double price and char sold (y/n), about every item I have how can I manage it?
It would look like this
Timberland, 40, n;
Gucci, 10, y; ..... etc..

I need it now, cause tomorrow I have a test, I appreciate your help, and sorry for my english!

Comment: [This reference of `ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

As for the problem with the double-printing, it's because the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you read from beyond the end of the file. That means your loop will iterate once to many.

I suggest you instead use `getline` to read the *complete* line (in the condition of the loop), and then use e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) to parse the line.

So do e.g.

```
while (std::getline(your, fullLine))
{
    std::istringstream istr(fullLine);

    getline(istr, st, ',');
    istr >> c;
    // etc.
}
```